# How to merge every two lines into one

Tags: text-processing

I have this file:

```
~path1/file1.txt ~path1/file1_newname
par1 par2 par 53
~path1/file2.txt ~path1/file2_newname
par1 par2
~path1/file3.txt ~path1/morepath/file3_newname
par31 par121
~path2/file1.txt ~path2/file1_newname
par87
~path2/file3.txt ~path2/file3_newname
par1
~path2/file4.txt ~path2/file4_newname
par2 par3 par4
~path3//path4/file3.txt ~path3/file4_newname
par13
```

I expect to get this at the end:

```
~path1/file1.txt ~path1/file1_newname par1 par2 par 53
~path1/file2.txt ~path1/file2_newname par1 par2
~path1/file3.txt ~path1/morepath/file3_newname par31 par121
~path2/file1.txt ~path2/file1_newname par87
~path2/file3.txt ~path2/file3_newname par1
~path2/file4.txt ~path2/file4_newname par2 par3 par4
~path3//path4/file3.txt ~path3/file4_newname par13
```

I tried to sort it via `sort -k` but I didn't succeed.

What should I do to sort it as well?

edit to show the new pattern after the answears:

```
~/path1/file1.cob ~/path1/file1_namename
 param1 param2 param90 ~/path1/file2.cob ~/path1/file2_namename
 param1 param2
~/path1/file3.cob ~/path1/path2/file3_namename
 param15 param124 ~/path2/file1.cob ~/path2/file1_namename.cob
 param55
~/path2/file2.cob ~/path2/file2_namename.cob
 param1 ~/path2/file5.cob ~/path4/file2_namename.cob param23
~/path3/file2.cob ~/path2/file4_namename.cob
 param2 param3 param4 ~/path3/path1/file3.cob ~/path3/file2_namename.cob
 param3
```

Comment: There's a couple of solutions at https://stackoverflow.com/q/9605232 
  I like https://stackoverflow.com/a/9605450 :-)

Comment: i've tried.
it gives me the same pattern in the question edit

Comment: Regarding that last addition to the question: What is the input when that output is produced and what did you _expect_ to get?

Comment: the output i want to get is the secound one.
the input is the first one, par1 is wrote in the quote but thats param in the reality

Answer (score 3):

Note that this has nothing to do with sorting. It's just joining lines together.

These solutions assume that you'd always want to join lines pairwise.

Using standard `sed`:

```
$ sed 'N; s/\n/ /' file
~path1/file1.txt ~path1/file1_newname par1 par2 par 53
~path1/file2.txt ~path1/file2_newname par1 par2
~path1/file3.txt ~path1/morepath/file3_newname par31 par121
~path2/file1.txt ~path2/file1_newname par87
~path2/file3.txt ~path2/file3_newname par1
~path2/file4.txt ~path2/file4_newname par2 par3 par4
~path3//path4/file3.txt ~path3/file4_newname par13
```

The short `sed` editing script will read a line and append the next line with the `N` command.  The appended line will be added to the pattern space (the "work buffer") with an embedded newline character, so swap that for a space with a substitution before the line is printed.

Or, with `paste`:

```
$ paste -d ' ' - - <file
~path1/file1.txt ~path1/file1_newname par1 par2 par 53
~path1/file2.txt ~path1/file2_newname par1 par2
~path1/file3.txt ~path1/morepath/file3_newname par31 par121
~path2/file1.txt ~path2/file1_newname par87
~path2/file3.txt ~path2/file3_newname par1
~path2/file4.txt ~path2/file4_newname par2 par3 par4
~path3//path4/file3.txt ~path3/file4_newname par13
```

This asks `paste` to produce two columns of output with a space in-between.  The columns are read from the lines in the input, giving the effect of joining the lines pairwise.

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '{ getline nextline; print $0, nextline }' file
~path1/file1.txt ~path1/file1_newname par1 par2 par 53
~path1/file2.txt ~path1/file2_newname par1 par2
~path1/file3.txt ~path1/morepath/file3_newname par31 par121
~path2/file1.txt ~path2/file1_newname par87
~path2/file3.txt ~path2/file3_newname par1
~path2/file4.txt ~path2/file4_newname par2 par3 par4
~path3//path4/file3.txt ~path3/file4_newname par13
```

Comment: hey thank you for your help.
i tried and the result was:
'''
~/path1/file1.cob ~/path1/file1_namename
 param1 param2 param90 ~/path1/file2.cob ~/path1/file2_namename
 param1 param2
~/path1/file3.cob ~/path1/path2/file3_namename
 param15 param124 ~/path2/file1.cob ~/path2/file1_namename.cob
 param55
~/path2/file2.cob ~/path2/file2_namename.cob
 param1 ~/path2/file5.cob ~/path4/file2_namename.cob param23
~/path3/file2.cob ~/path2/file4_namename.cob
 param2 param3 param4 ~/path3/path1/file3.cob ~/path3/file2_namename.cob
 param3'''

Comment: the opposite pattern

Comment: @bishbash Sorry, I can't see the newlines since comments do not allow for good formatting (the text also does not look like the text in your question). Can you explain what you mean by "opposite pattern" (opposite to what, and what pattern?). Also, am I to assume that you _want_ the opposite pattern (whatever that means).

Comment: i'll edit the post

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, I think this could work for you (using GNU `sed`):

```
sed '1~2N;s/\n/ /' file
```

Comment: hey thank you for your help,
i tried that but it also did that:
'
~/path1/file1.cob ~/path1/file1_namename
 param1 param2 param90 ~/path1/file2.cob ~/path1/file2_namename
 param1 param2
~/path1/file3.cob ~/path1/path2/file3_namename
 param15 param124 ~/path2/file1.cob ~/path2/file1_namename.cob
 param55
~/path2/file2.cob ~/path2/file2_namename.cob
 param1 ~/path2/file5.cob ~/path4/file2_namename.cob param23
~/path3/file2.cob ~/path2/file4_namename.cob
 param2 param3 param4 ~/path3/path1/file3.cob ~/path3/file2_namename.cob
 param3
'

Comment: the opposite pattern